# Nodejs + connect-assetmanager + uglifyJs

Tags: node.js, assets, uglifyjs

I'm using nodejs(v0.8.2) with the connect-assetmanager middleware to bundle and minify my js files using uglifyJs(v1.3.2). My configure is like
`

```
var assets = 
    {
    'loginJs':{
        'debug': false,
        'route': /\/js\/login.js/
        , 'path': './public/scripts/'
        , 'dataType': 'javascript'
        , 'files': [
            'configs.js',
            'WMTX.Web.Library.js',
            'sso.js',
            'index.js'
        ]
        ,'postManipulate': {
                 '^': [
                assetHandler.uglifyJsOptimize
            ]
        } 
    },
    assetManager = require('connect-assetmanager'),
    assetsManagerMiddleware = assetManager(assets);
    app.configure(function(){
    app.use("/", assetsManagerMiddleware, express.static(o.paths.root));
});
```

`

But when I launch the application, an error occured:

> at new JS_Parse_Error (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager-handlers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse-js.js:263:22)
>       at js_error (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager-handlers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse-js.js:271:15)
>       at parse_error (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager-handlers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse-js.js:367:17)
>       at Object.next_token [as input] (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager-handlers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse-js.js:613:17)
>       at next (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager-handlers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse-js.js:718:37)
>       at Object.parse (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager-handlers\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse-js.js:704:19)
>       at Array.uglifyJsOptimize [as 0] (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager-handlers\lib\handlers.js:57:26)
>       at modify (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager\lib\assetmanager.js:275:42)
>       at module.exports.manipulate (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager\lib\assetmanager.js:281:7)
>       at Function.module.exports.generateCache.settings.forEach.userAgentMatches.forEach.content (E:\work\siteexV2\IDE\node_modules\connect-assetmanager\lib\assetmanager.js:231:11)

I tried minify those js using uglifyJs in command-line, all files can be minified successfully.
Please anyone who knows what's going wrong give me some help, this is driving me mad!
Thanks so much

Comment: Let's know which are these lines, mentioned in exception, please.

Comment: Lines mentioned in the exception are in the "connect-assetmanager-handlers"'s source code, I didn't touch any of them.

Comment: Take a look at these lines, I usually find problems like this. I can't help with node.js, unfortunately.

Comment: even nobody counter this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with connect-assetmanager, but there are some syntaxerrors in your code.

As far as I understand what you are trying to do, you forgot to end your declaration of "assets" with a semi-colon. You appear to be doing the same thing after calling require(). This is the corrected code:

```
var assets = 
   {
   'loginJs':{
       'debug': false,
       'route': /\/js\/login.js/,
       'path': './public/scripts/',
       'dataType': 'javascript',
       'files': [
           'configs.js',
           'WMTX.Web.Library.js',
           'sso.js',
           'index.js'
       ],
       'postManipulate': {
           '^': [assetHandler.uglifyJsOptimize]
       }
   }; // <- note the semicolon

assetManager = require('connect-assetmanager'); // <- and here
assetsManagerMiddleware = assetManager(assets);

app.configure(function() {
    app.use("/", assetsManagerMiddleware, express.static(o.paths.root));
});
```

Comment: Thanks dow, but syntax is not the problem because the code had been compiled successfully. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry buddy, but syntax _is_ the problem. Your code is interpreted as a giant object now, if interpreted at all.

Comment: Not correct. I do not omit semicolons in my code, but JS allows it.

Comment: Semicolon insertion rules off ECMA-262:

When the program contains a token that is not allowed by the formal grammar, then a semicolon is inserted if 

(a) there is a line break at that point, or 
(b) the unexpected token was a closing brace.

When the end of a file is reached, if the program cannot be parsed otherwise, then a semicolon is inserted.

When a "restricted production" is encountered and contains a line terminator in a place where the grammar contains the annotation "[no LineTerminator here]", then a semicolon is inserted.